# Can I use Regexp in Route::group without unnecessary parameters? Laravel5

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

Can I use Regexp in Route::group without unnecessary parameters?
I want to separate routing, whether url contains subdomain.

Using following code, When I access 'http://test.main.com/site/12', output 'test'.

```
# app/Http/routes.php

Route::group(array('domain' => "{subdomain}.main.com"),function()
{
  Route::get('/site/{id}', 'SiteController@show');
}
```

,

```
# app/Http/Controller/SiteController.php

public function show($id)
{               
  // When I access 'http://test.main.com/site/12', I check 'test'.
  var_dump($id);
}
```

If I code following , I can get `12`. But `$subdomain` is unnecessary parameter.

```
# app/Http/Controller/SiteController.php

public function show($subdomain, $id)
{               
  // When I access 'http://test.main.com/site/12', I check '12'.
  var_dump($id);
}
```

Appreciate any suggestions you can make.

Comment: follow this http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Comment: Can I use this for subdomain?

Comment: I also asked the same a few months ago but I can't seem to find the question. The short answer is **no**, you cannot. Laravel doesn't have a *don't inject that parameter into controller methods* functionality.

Comment: I see. Thank you for answering. @Hkan

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated to use it in the controller but there is a way to do it:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.website.com', 'before' => 'subDomain'], function()
{

    // All application routes

});

Route::filter('subDomain', function($route)
{
    $domain = $route->getParameter('subdomain');            

    Session::put('subDomain', $domain);
});
```

If you want to handle it in the route.php simply use:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($subdomain, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Your Controller looks then like this:

```
public function show($id)
{               
  $subDomain = Session::get('subdomain');
  var_dump($id);
}
```

Comment: I want to handle it in the route.php. But your code is to include unnecessary parametor, `$account`.

Comment: Updated the code. Both parts are be placed in the route.php . It depends where you want to work with the information. If you want to use your `SiteController` you need the first solution (I prefer it). You can't pass the `subdomain` as a third parameter so you need the trick with the session.

Comment: I tried first solution. Bud it is not working.
output value is 'test'.
It does not matter whether `$account` or `$subdomain`.
`$subdomain` is unnecessary parametor.

Comment: You get the suddomain with `$subDomain = Session::get('subdomain');` Thought you know how to handle with sessions.

Comment: `Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.'.getenv('DOMAIN'), 'before' => 'subDomain'], function()
     {
         Route::get('/site/{id}', 'SiteController@show');
     });
     Route::filter('subDomain', function($route)
     {
           $domain = $route->getParameter('subdomain');
    
               Session::put('subDomain', $domain);
     });
`
I can get `$subDomain`('test'). But I can't get `$id`(12).

Comment: You should be able to call it in the Controller like you did it before. It works for me....

Comment: I see.Thank you politely tell me.
I'll retry it.
When I can get, I tell you.